# How to disable syslog messaging to /var/log/syslog

Tags: linux, logging, disk-space, syslog

I'm working on a centralized logging solution using the ELK stack and Kafka.

I'm running Ubuntu Xenial on all the machines, and I'm using Rsyslog with omkafka to write all log messages to a kafka topic.
The pipeline is:

```
+-----------+      +-----------+      +--------------+        +-------------------+
|           |      |           |      |              |        |                   |
|  Rsyslog  +------>   Kafka   +------>   Logstash   +-------->   Elasticsearch   |
| (omkafka) |      |           |      |              |        |                   |
|           |      +-----------+      +--------------+        +-------------------+
+-----------+
```

Since I now have this solution in place I've turned the verbosity up on most logging to have the biggest amount of info available.

This, however, has exposed a big pain point: /var/log/syslog is growing at a rate where the daily logrotate will not work, the disks fill in ~4 hours.
Since I don't exactly need the file contents, I was thinking about disabling logging to that file altogether. I've been searching through the Rsyslog docs and can't find any info on this.

How do I disable file logging in this case?

The other alternative, that I wanted to avoid, is to turn the logrotate frequency up to hourly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably all you need is to comment out following (or similar) line in your /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
syslog.*                    /var/log/syslog
```

Or reduce it to some more limiting level, like warn or err:

```
syslog.err                 /var/log/syslog
```

For complete list of priority keywords consult the 'man rsyslog.conf'.

Comment: I'm going to try that out then. For reference the file under Xenial is /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

Comment: Tested, works :)